# Entire function maps bounded sets to bounded sets

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I was doing some problems in Complex Analysis… And I came across this.

**Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be entire. Then for any bounded set $B$, f ($B$) is bounded.**

Now I know that if an entire function is constant then the above statement is necessarily true.

What about non-constant entire function?

All I know is that a non-constant entire function is unbounded. (By Liouville’s Theorem)

I am summarising my doubts here:

$1)$ What is the image of a bounded set under this non-constant entire function?

$2)$ What can we say about its image on the unbounded set?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: that's true for continuous functions in general, nothing to do with entire (compacts go to compacts and any bounded set is included in a compact set)

Comment: That just means entire is an overkill//

Comment: for this assertion of course but entire functions have specific properties otherwise (for example the preimage of any point but at most one is infinite and roughly of the same density in large disks again excepting at most two points, an entire function cannot go to infinity at infinity (in the sense $\lim_{|z| \to \infty}|f(z)|=\infty$) unless is a polynomial etc)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Have you ever looked at the graph of $\arctan\,?$

Comment: Okay I overlooked what I was asking… Can a non constant entire function map unbounded sets to unbounded sets?

Comment: Not only can an entire function do that, it [has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) to do that when the unbounded set is $\mathbb C\,$.

Comment: Ohh right… Thanks for your time… I don’t know what is happening to me…I am asking such trivial questions